# WP-Syntax in post comments

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to apply the syntax highlighting of the WP-Syntax plugin into post comments. The changelog of the plugin suggests that this has already been done. Has anyone does this before?

If they've not implemented this, how can I do it? Which parts of the code should I read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the plugin solved the problem. The plugin uses the comment_text filter by default (one "before" and one "after"). Change it to the get_comment_text filter worked!

Comment: Not working at my end, check with mysql, comments inserted as <pre lang="xml"> ... </pre> , look it deleted all the xml and html tags?